# Xcode, why can't I see any build results and why do errors flicker in red?

Tags: xcode

I can't see any build results, I think I have an extra window open, as I have a small holder icon at the bottom / middle of the window.

[image]

Also errors flicker in red, see this [video](http://www.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/34cd6232-ce43-424d-b53e-d00f54de0b17)...

Any ideas how to fix these ?

I'm re-installed xcode 3.2.5 but it doesn't help.

Comment: Try dragging the little 'dot' up to the top of the window? Does it happen when you create a new project?

Comment: Ahh its not in other projects. No I can't drag the dot :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your project, open up a Terminal window, cd to the .xcodeproj directory, delete all files with your username in them, e.g. `username.pbxuser`, `username.mode1v3` (don't worry - they are just user-specific settings, like window positions, breakpoints, etc). **DO NOT delete** `project.pbxproj`. Then try again...